# Proxmox VE 5. How create multiples users

Tags: proxmox

I want to create multiple users on Proxmox ve 5, my problem is that I've created them in /etc/pve/user.cfg but I can not assign them password. Somebody can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just create "normal" system users with

`adduser Username`

Then add those users to Proxmox via GUI.

In Datacenter >> Permissions >> Users >>

click adduser and enter just created usernames. It will work.

Because if you create users only in GUI of proxmox, you wont be able to assign a passwd. You must first add an user to the system and then just link it in Proxmox GUI (or /etc/pve/user.cfg) but I recommend to use the GUI way. ( Sometimes, when you edditing a config file directly, cluster can fall apart)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a password to a proxmox user with following command:

```
/usr/bin/pvesh set /access/password --userid youruser --password yourpassword
```

See also:
https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/User_Management